# PHP and Enum Troubles

Tags: php, database, enums, enumeration, enumerable

I've looked everywhere and cannot seem to figure this out. My issue is that I am trying to use the 'enum' for rank that is in my database but keep getting errors.  What I have below I'd like to be able to display in a specific div depending on what rank a member is.  This is what I have so far, where am I going wrong?  If someone could shed some light on if this is even correct or what I need to do to make this work, I'd greatly appreciate it.

PHP:

```
class Rank
{
  // If no value is given during object construction this value is used
  const __default = 1;
  // Our enum values
  const Registered       = 1;
  const Legend           = 2;
  const Inactive         = 3;
  const Greenhorn        = 4;
  const FullMember       = 5;
  const JuniorAdmin      = 6;
  const SeniorAdmin      = 7;
  const Leader           = 8;
  const Founder          = 9;
  const OriginalFounder  = 10;
}

$registered     = new Rank(Rank::REGISTERED);
$legend         = new Rank(Rank::LEGEND);
$inactive           = new Rank(Rank::INACTIVE);
$greenhorn          = new Rank(Rank::GREENHORN);
$fullmember     = new Rank(Rank::FULLMEMBER);
$junioradmin        = new Rank(Rank::JUNIORADMIN);
$senioradmin        = new Rank(Rank::SENIORADMIN);
$leader         = new Rank(Rank::LEADER);
$founder            = new Rank(Rank::FOUNDER);
$originalfounder    = new Rank(Rank::ORIGINALFOUNDER);
$fail              = 1;

function responsibilities(Rank $rank)
{
  if (Rank::REGISTERED == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being a registered member.\n";
  } elseif (Rank::LEGEND == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being Legend.\n";
  } elseif (Rank::INACTIVE == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being Inactive./n";
  } elseif (Rank::GREENHORN == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being a Greenhorn./n";
  } elseif (Rank::FULLMEMBER == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being a Full Member./n";
  } elseif (Rank::JUNIORADMIN == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being a Junior Admin./n";
  } elseif (Rank::SENIORADMIN == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being a Senior Admin./n";
  } elseif (Rank::LEADER == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being a Leader./n";
  } elseif (Rank::FOUNDER == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being a Founder./n";
  } elseif (Rank::ORIGINALFOUNDER == $rank) {
    echo "Post something about being an Original Founder./n";
  }
}

responsibilities($registered);
responsibilities($legend);
responsibilities($inactive);
responsibilities($greenhorn);
responsibilities($fullmember);
responsibilities($junioradmin);
responsibilities($senioradmin);
responsibilities($leader);
responsibilities($founder);
responsibilities($originalfounder);

responsibilities($fail);
```

HTML:

```
<p><?php echo $rank ?></p>
```

Comment: And waht is the error that you receive ?

Comment: It keeps throwing me errors on specific lines in my php.  Right now it's on line42...

Comment: Undefined class constant 'REGISTERED'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use the [SplEnum](http://php.net/manual/en/class.splenum.php) class to make an enum. In order to have such an enum, you need your enum class to extend the `SplEnum` abstract class.

```
class Fruit extends SplEnum
{
    const __default = self::Apple; // default value; could also be __default = 0;
    // values
    const Apple = 0;
    const Orange = 1;
}
```

I haven't tested it, but I'm fairly certain that constants in an enum are case-sensitive. That is, if you define an enum `Fruit` like above, you can use `Fruit::Orange` but not `Fruit::ORANGE`. I think the normal convention is to use all UPPERCASE, since they are constants.